# Saving to a many_many relationship with a ListBoxField

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've created a `DataObject` called Service and I've got a many_many relationship to RelatedServices as follows:

```
class Service extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array (
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'Description' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $many_many = array (
        'RelatedServices' => 'RelatedService'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));
        $services = $this->get()->where("\"Service\".\"Name\" != '$this->Name'")->map('ID', 'Name')->toArray();
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
            TextField::create('Name'),
            TextField::create('Description'),
            ListBoxField::create('RelatedServices', 'Related services')->setMultiple(true)->setSource($services)
        ));
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

and:

```
class RelatedService extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array (
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array (
        'RelatedServices' => 'RelatedService'
    );
}
```

This is being used in a ModelAdmin and the service works right including the related services text area, however it doesn't save. I did it previously that it was in a seperate tab in the CMS and had `RelatedService` have and admin section which looking through the DB looked like it worked however I thought it was an unnecessary section so tried to make it all in one and now no longer saves to the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the 'RelatedService' class, as you are referencing to the class you are working in. So relating to the class 'Service' itself would make more sense.
The reason why your code won't work is because you have got your relations mixed up.

```
class Service extends DataObject{
    private static $db = array (
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'Description' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $many_many = array (
        'RelatedServices' => 'Service'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array (
        'ParentServices' => 'Service'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));
        $services = $this->get()->where("\"Service\".\"Name\" != '$this->Name'")->map('ID', 'Name')->toArray();
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
            TextField::create('Name'),
            TextField::create('Description'),
            ListBoxField::create('RelatedServices', 'Related services')->setMultiple(true)->setSource($services)
        ));
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did think it should just relate to itself but being new to the framework wasn't sure how the many_many, belongs_many_many would work.